# Upgraded to Ubuntu Mate 22.04 computer shuts down after about a minute after screensaver is on

Tags: 22.04, screensaver

When the screensaver starts, the computer turns off.  The computer has power, but just turns off.  Any idea how or what is causing this?  Is it a bug?

Comment: What happens if you press a button? Could it be that it is suspending instead of turning off? Have you looked at the power settings? Do you have it set to sleep/suspend after a time of inactivity?